# Raspberry GY-271 HMC5883L Errno 121

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, i2c, gyroscope, errno

I just can't read my GY-271 HMC5883L module. I always get "OSerror: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error" as an error. Can someone help me here?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    hmc5883l = i2c_hmc5883l.i2c_hmc5883l(1)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/software/i2clibraries/i2c_hmc5883l.py", line 29, in __init__
    self.setScale(gauss)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/software/i2clibraries/i2c_hmc5883l.py", line 76, in setScale
    self.setOption(self.ConfigurationRegisterB, self.scale_reg)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/software/i2clibraries/i2c_hmc5883l.py", line 87, in setOption
    self.bus.write_byte(register, options)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/software/i2clibraries/i2c.py", line 14, in write_byte
    writing_bytes(self.addr, *bytes))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/quick2wire_api-0.0.0.2-py3.7.egg/quick2wire/i2c.py", line 78, in transaction
OSError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error
```

Code:

```
from i2clibraries import i2c_hmc5883l

hmc5883l = i2c_hmc5883l.i2c_hmc5883l(1)

hmc5883l.setContinuousMode()
hmc5883l.setDeclination(4, 22)

print(hmc5883l)
```

i2cdetect -y 1:

```
i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 0d -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`The OSError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O Error` indicates that an I<sup>2</sup>C device isn't connected to the bus. Make sure that the sensors are securely connected to the I<sup>2</sup>C bus.

Comment: When I type "i2cdetect -y 1" it shows me. So the module is connected. I've already checked the wiring several times.

Comment: The sensor may be connected when it runs the `i2cdetect -y 1` command. However, when you try to run the program, one of the jumpers may cause the I2C communication to break. This problem is hardware related.